# OpenCV triangulatePoints - what are the correct coordinates to feed it with?

Tags: c++, opencv, triangulation

Previously, I was using another method to determine 3D positions from two 2D images. For that (mediocre) method I had to get 2D coordinates with a point of origin in the center of the image. Because of that, I get a lot of negative values. OpenCV normally uses the let bottom corner as the coordinates origin point (no negative values at all)

The app user is supposed to be able to use either method. Can I keep collecting 2D coordinates that way, or do I have to change it? If not, do I have to use the new center point of the image (result of `cv::stereoCalibrate`) instead of the default one, (`frame.cols/2` , frame.rows/2)?

Comment: the opencv origin is almost definitely top left

Comment: @chris my bad, I've written the other part so long ago.... I simply didn't remember

Answer (score 0):

When using OpenCV's `triangulatePoints`, you need to pass as arguments:

- `projectionMatrixA` - implicitly contains intrinsic camera parameters (focal length & **Principal Point Offset** which is the pixel offset from the left and from the top that should be considered as 0,0)
- `projectionMatrixB` - besides intrinsic camera parameteres, projection matrix also reflects the position of the camera in relation to some coordinate system. So if you have two identical cameras, the two projection matrices would still differ because they are positioned differently.
- 2D points that are a result of 3D points being projected using `projectionMatrixA`
- 2D points that are a result of 3D points being projected using `projectionMatrixB`

To answer the question, there is nothing wrong with the fact that 2D points have negative values.

AFAIK, in the `calib` module, when dealing with 2D points (pixel coordinates), the coordinate (0,0) should always be around the center of the image and not in the top left corner. So naturally, any points in the left region of the image have x < 0, and any point in the upper region of the image have y < 0.